# How to apply masking in Dynamic crm 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Is there is some way to apply mask on fields in crm 2013 on forms, using any jQuery and jQuery mask plugins.

I read from http://taoofcrm.com/2011/05/19/crm-field-masking-with-jquery/
but it not worked for me on Dynamic crm 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In crm 2011 input field ID is the name of attribute, while in crm 2013 input field ID is the name of attribute plus "_i" (may be "i" denote an input).

So if we have attribute name "name" then input field ID for this attribute in 2011 is "name" and in 2013 it is "name_i".

Following is the Source view of input field of an attribute on the form in crm 2011 and crm 2013.

**Input field in crm 2011**

```
 <input id="name" tabindex="1010" class="ms-crm-Input ms-crm-Text" style="-ms-ime-mode: auto;" type="text" maxlength="255" value="test" attrformat="text" attrpriv="7" attrname="name" req="2">
```

**Input field in crm 2013**

```
<input id="name_i" title="" class="ms-crm-InlineInput" aria-labelledby="name_c name_w" style="-ms-ime-mode: active;" type="text" maxlength="160" attrname="name" attrpriv="7" controlmode="normal" defaultvalue="Blue Yonder Airlines (sample)">
```

If you applying masking in crm 2011, then please see [here](http://taoofcrm.com/2011/05/19/crm-field-masking-with-jquery/)!, or just use following code.

```
//Include jquery and jqueryMask plugin file on form you apply masking.
function Mask(field, format)
{ 
$("#"+field).mask(format);
}

// call this function on form load event 
function maskFields()
{
Mask("address1_postalcode", "99999-9999");
Mask("telephone1", "(999) 999-9999");
Mask("telephone2", "(999) 999-9999");
Mask("fax", "(999) 999-9999");

}
```

**For crm 2013** you should attach "_i" with field name like.

```
function Mask(field, format)
{ 
$("#"+field+"_i").mask(format);
}
```

But also still not working because in crm 2013 input fields are created on execution time.
you should apply masking on click event of input, **or** just got focus of attribute before apply masking e.g.

```
//Include jquery and jqueryMask plugin file on form you apply masking.
function Mask(field, format) {
  //first check whether attribute exist or not
    var oCtrl = Xrm.Page.getControl(field);
    if (oCtrl != null) {

        oCtrl.setFocus(true);
        $("#" + field + "_i").mask(format);
    }
} 

// call this function on form load event 
function maskFields()
{
Mask("address1_postalcode", "99999-9999");
Mask("telephone1", "(999) 999-9999");
Mask("telephone2", "(999) 999-9999");
Mask("fax", "(999) 999-9999");

}
```

Worked well for crm 2013.