# Jscript to disable view picker on lookup doesn't work in CRM 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working with MS Dynamics CRM 2013 and I am facing with the next issue:
in CRM 2011 I disabled view and entity selection on lookup by using next jscript :

```
document.getElementById("lookup_id").setAttribute("disableViewPicker", "1");
document.getElementById("lookup_id").setAttribute("defaulttype", "1"); 
document.getElementById("lookup_id").setAttribute("lookuptypenames", "account:1:Account");
document.getElementById("lookup_id").setAttribute("lookuptypes", "1");
```

But after migration to Dynamics Crm 2013 this script doesn't work any more.

Can you help me with this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add "_i" with attributeId e.g
contactid is your lookup attribute name, then you should pass like

```
document.getElementById("contactid_i").setAttribute("disableViewPicker", "1");
document.getElementById("contactid_i").setAttribute("defaulttype", "1");
document.getElementById("contactid_i").setAttribute("lookuptypenames","account:1:Account");
document.getElementById("contactid_i").setAttribute("lookuptypes", "1");
```

In crm 2011 attribute input id is same as attribute name, but in crm 2013 attribute input id is attribute name plus "_i"(perhaps "_i" denotes an input).
 I try this "_i" in masking and multipicker lists working perfect for 2013. Hope it helps in your case.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21552357/1915855

Comment: This work fine with "_i". Today i have tested it while upgrading js to crm 2013

Answer (score 0):

you can also disable it in customization,
In the form, when editing the lookup

select in "View selector" -> off

Answer (score -2):

Best practice is to use the Xrm.Page object:

```javascript
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("lookup_id").setDisabled(true);
```

Gareth Tucker has a great [JavaScript reference for Dynamics CRM](http://garethtuckercrm.com/2011/03/16/jscript-reference-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/).

Using the DOM directly is unsupported in Dynamics CRM; the current code you have may break again after an update-rollup is installed. See the [JavaScript Programming Best Pratices on this MSDN page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584.aspx)

Comment: I don't think that you can achieve what they are trying to do with a supported method. That code should be to disable (for example in an activity party) the possibility to choose from accounts or contacts and force the user to pick, let's say, contacts only .